# How to make last command as an infinite loop in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I want to fetch information from server every time whether the person is logging in to the system every time and if he logged in into the system that information must be store in a file.I need to make that script to work infinite time so that every time he logged in to system it will be stored in that file.At present i was here

```
      last grep id > filename  // fetching information into file
      tail -r filename         // reversing the info from current date
```

Comment: Not clear. Infinite loop / every logging?? What do you want exactly?

Comment: I mean when ever if a person logged into the system that last command need to fetch that information and stored in a file which means that command needs to work continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your script repeating itself using every 5 minutes with

```
while true; do
   last | grep id >> file
   sleep 300
done
```

This will introduce more problems, such as double registrations in the file, what interval to use, hot to get your loop restarted after reboot and what to do when your script is killed?
Slightly better is adding in entry in crontab for polling at fixed times.
When you like to audit hen the user is logged in and you do not want to install some accounting system, why not add something to /etc/profile or /etc/bash.bashrc? Or use the accounting in last?

Comment: This will works if we runs the script only. Our aim is to run this script continuously even though we don't execute

Comment: Crontab: `* * * * * last | grep -m1 id >> /home/arun/wtmp`.  For what purpose do you want to have the script running continuously, when you can have all login times of the user in a file or even get mail when (s)he signs on? Continuously? Do you want last called every millisecond?

Comment: I want that script running every time when user signs in.. and that script should run continuously... and along with the date please append the output of the commands "tty" and "id" to the end of each line

Comment: Look in /etc/password what shell the user has and start testing with the /etc login settings.